# history of a specific table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can we find the history of values, updates, deletes or inserts of a specific table?

I don't have the access to create a `stored procedure`. Can you please provide me a query in the answer or some other way to find the history?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind.

1.)  If you have auditing enabled, you are all set.  But, I'm guessing if that was the case, you wouldn't be asking the question.  If you think this request will come up again, you should investigate setting up auditing for future requests.

2.)  If auditing isn't set up, there's LogMiner, which allows you to examine the contents of the archived and online redo logs.  This is probably your only solution, if you need the details of inserts, updates, deletes to a specific table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i never knew about these! Thanks for this info.. +1 .. but I think we need to go DBA. or have privileges?

Comment: Yes, if you're not a DBA, you would need to work with your DBA, both for enabling auditing, or for using logminer.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible if `FLASHBACK` has been enabled over the schema or table. Most critical tables could have that enabled. Please check with DBA on this. If you have DBA access, then select the table name in `SQL Developer` , press `Shift+F4` and move to Flashback tab to find details.

if enabled, you can use the below query ( just a sample)

```
SELECT * FROM employee AS OF TIMESTAMP 
   TO_TIMESTAMP('2003-04-04 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
   WHERE name = 'JOHN';
```

if not enabled, you may have to write `TRIGGERS` for evry `DML` over that table. I agree the history of data before `TRIGGERS` are gone for ever, unless `DBA` is able to do some magic with redo logs..!

Comment: http://psoug.org/reference/flash_query.html u can refer here! can u paste the query u use as condition.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2103.htm

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I saw that already. Unable to find the history of updates for a table under owner other than `SYS` using that table.